# Querying range from collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I can query the first 20 datapoints from my collection using the following code

```
db.collections.aggregate([{$project: {"text": 1}}, {$limit:20}])
```

How do I query a range from my collection? Let's say, from data points 20 through 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the possible ways :

1. Using db..find()

   db.collection.find({},{"text": 1}).skip(20).limit(20);
2. Using aggregation framework

   db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {"text": 1}}, { $skip : 20 }, {$limit:20}])